# C, stop reading lines once enter is pressed

Tags: c

I need to read a line which can contain integers and real numbers and operators('+','-','*' and '/') separated by spaces. 
For example: 9 2e2 + 5.0 -
There is no restriction on the length of the input.
Once the line is read, numbers have to be separated converted and stored in a stack. Depending on the operator, we perform operation on the top two numbers in the stack. For the above example I need to store 9 and then store 2e2 in stack. Then pop those two back and perform addition (+). Store result on stack and then store 5.0 on stack and lastly perform subtraction. Once enter is pressed it should print the output, here -204.
I am having problem with reading and storing the inputs.

I used reading inputs with scanf, but it doesn't stop reading once enter is pressed. So, its not printing any output.

```
char c[100];

while(should stop once enter is pressed)

{

   scanf("%s",c);

   //code

}
```

please help, thank you.

Comment: `scanf("%s",c);` already implies that ENTER gets pressed...

Comment: OT: to avoid any buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior.  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.   Also, `%s` will stop at the first `white space`, so will only (using your example) input: `9`.  Suggest using `fgets()` or (due to the unknown max length of the input line) use: `getline()`.   Then use `strtok()` (or similar) to parse each of the operands

Comment: if you want to use `scanf()` to read a line, then use something like: `scanf( "%99[^\n]", c)`  which will stop when a newline (or 99 characters) is encountered.  Note: the '\n' will still be in `stdin` so that should be consumed (perhaps via `getchar()`) before reading the next line

Comment: @user3629249 `scanf( "%99[^\n]", c)` fails to read anything into `c` if input begins with `'\n'`, leaving `c` unassigned.

Comment: @chux,  did you read all of my prior comment, including the detail about the need to consume the newline?

Comment: "There is no restriction on the length of the input." is not a reasonable coding requirement given the range of nasty users out there..  Use a large value such as 4096.  _No restriction_ invites code exploits of attempting to overwhelming resources with lines of many gigabytes.

Comment: @user3629249 Consuming the  `'\n'`  via `getchar()` still leaves `c` unassigned when the line of input began with `'\n'`.

Comment: When calling C library functions, like `scanf()`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversion specifiers.  I..E. `if( scanf("%99s",c) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input anything\n" );`  and skip any code that is expecting `c[]` to contain anything

Comment: @user3629249 thanks! strtok() worked. But when I use a char pointer for the tokens, how do I decide if it points to a single character, here the arithmetic operators? Because it misreads negative inputs as "-" operator.

Comment: how to determine the number of characters in a 'token' returned from `strtok()`?  `char *token = strtok( ...., " ");  size_t numBytes = strlen( token );`

Comment: use `fgets(3)` for that.  then parse the string for the tokens you need.